# Setting a hidden field and accessing it in MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, hiddenfield

I have the need to create a hidden field in  of my table. Later upon button click, i need to retrieve the data saved in the hidden field. Below is the code:

```html
<td>
<input id="hdnr<%=RowNumber%>c<%=ColumnNumber%>" type="hidden" value="{{Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Key)}}" />
</td>
```

Where rownumber and colnumber are variables.
Later in jquery, upon button click, I am attempting to retrieve the value of the hidden field as per the code below:

```js
var value = $('#hdnr'+i+'c'+j).val();
alert(value);
```

Somewhere something is wrong. Either the value is not getting saved in the html tag or it is not being retrieved correctly.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your value in the input is not correct. You can put the value directly from the model.

```
<input id="hdnr<%=RowNumber%>c<%=ColumnNumber%>" type="hidden" value="<% model.Key %>" />
```

if you want to use the helper, but in this case the id will be generated automatically. :

```
Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Key)
```

You can still add custom attribute. I'm not sure of the syntax :

```
Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Key, { @class = "myClass" })
```